# Proving associativity in monoidal category: Free Monoid construction.

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am filling in the details of Mac Lane's proof of the following: If monoidal category $B$ has countable coproducts, and if the functors $-\square  a$ and $a\square -$ preserve them, then the evident forgetful functor $U$ from $\text{Mon}_{B}$ to the underlying category $B$ has a left adjoint. The proof is straightforward enough, except that I can't seem to verify that $\mu (1\square \mu )=\mu (\mu \square 1)\alpha $.

The functor $F$ takes each $a\in B$ to $\coprod _{n}a^{n}$, and $\mu $ is defined by juxtaposition; formally, by producing a unique arrow $\phi :\coprod _{m,n}a^{m}\square a^{n}\rightarrow \coprod _{k}a^{k}$, from the UMP of the coproduct. I have been able to show associativity in $Set$, but I can't seem to produce the right diagram to show this in general. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. It's my first pass at the subject and I want to dot the i's and cross the t's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show that the outer pentagon of the following diagram commutes.
[image]
The middle square commutes because the arrows going upwards are, on the individual summand $a^k\otimes(a^l\otimes a^m)$, the tensor product of the inclusions $i_k:a^k\to\coprod a^k,\ i_l,\ i_m$, so this is just naturality of $\alpha$.
Zooming into the diagram, the right hand square looks like this

[image]

Here every triangle and square commutes. In a similar manner, one can show that the left hand square of the first diagram commutes. It follows that $\mu(\mu\otimes1)\alpha = \mu(1\otimes\mu)$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I got something similar, but the middle square is not a naturality square in $\alpha $, but it does commute because the isomorphism $\theta :\coprod a\bigotimes b_{n}\rightarrow a\bigotimes \coprod b_{n}$ is natural in $a$, and the upward arrows are interated instances of $\theta $. I do not see why the lower triangle commutes however.

Comment: @Chilango: I figured that the composition
$$\textstyle a^k⊗(a^l⊗a^m)→∐_{k,l,m}a^k⊗(a^l⊗a^m)→∐a^k⊗(∐a^l⊗∐a^m)$$
is the tensor product $i_k⊗(i_l⊗i_m)$, which composed with $\alpha$ is the same as $(i_k⊗i_l)⊗i_m\circ\alpha$.

Comment: The lower triangle commutes because when we compose either path with the canonical map $i_{k,l,m}:a^k⊗(a^l⊗a^m)→∐_{k,l,m}a^k⊗(a^l⊗a^m)$, we get the composite
$$\textstyle a^k⊗(a^l⊗a^m)→a^{k+l+m}\to∐_p a^p$$

Comment: @Srefan: Got it. Your explanation was very clear. I guess you could say that the lower triangle commutes, just by invoking the coherence theorem before applying $\coprod $. Thanks again!

Comment: If my answer was helpful (which I assume it was), don't forget to upvote and/or accept :-)

Comment: I don't have upvoting privileges yet but I did accept. Could you comment on Kevin Carlson's answer above? He claims the result is only an application of the coherence theorem.

Comment: @Chilango: That's strange ... You have 350 rep, but voting up requires only 15 rep.

Comment: @Chilango: Kevin's proof only compares maps starting at $\coprod a^k\oplus a^m\oplus a^n$, but we want to compare maps starting at $∐a^k⊗∐a^m⊗∐a^n$. So I'd say it is incomplete. It actually just argues with the commutativity of the lower triangle in my diagram.

Comment: Yes, I guess I can upvote and I just did. If I could do it twice I would. Your explanations are very clear. Where I live I have literally no one to talk math with and I learn it all by reading books and doing  exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Your first map
$$\coprod_{k,m,n} a^k\otimes(a^m\otimes a^n)\to Fb\otimes(\coprod_{m,n} a^m\otimes a^n)\to Fb\otimes (Fb\otimes Fb)\to^{\mu(1\otimes \mu)} Fb$$
is given on components $a^k\otimes (a^m\otimes a^n)$ by the composition of the associators $a^k\otimes(a^m\otimes a^n)\to a^k\otimes a^{m+n}\to a^{k+m+n}$. The other map is given by the composition of associators $a^k\otimes(a^m\otimes a^n)\to (a^k\otimes a^m)\otimes a^n\to a^{k+m}\otimes a^n\to a^{k+m+n}$. So this is just the coherence theorem applied to iterates of $\alpha$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The two paths you wrote are certainly equal by coherence, but if $\alpha _{m,n}$ is the canonical arrow: $a^{m}\bigotimes a^{n}\rightarrow a^{m+n}$, then $\mu $ is defined by $\coprod \alpha _{m,n}\circ \theta \circ \theta$, where $\theta \circ \theta $ is the isomorphism $\coprod a^{m}\bigotimes \coprod a^{n}\rightarrow \coprod a^{m}\bigotimes a^{n}$ given by the UMP of the coproduct. I do not see how you get from the paths involving the associators, to $\mu $.