# Monad of possibly infinite lists

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoid, monads

It is well-known that if $T\colon\mathrm{Sets}\to\mathrm{Sets}$ is the monad which takes a set $S$ to the set of lists of elements of $S$, i.e., $\bigsqcup_{n\ge0} S^n$, with the monad structure $\mu\colon T\circ T\implies T$ given by concatenation, i.e.,
$$ S^{k_1}\times\cdots\times S^{k_m}\xrightarrow\mu S^{k_1+\cdots+k_m}:
((x_{1,1},\dots,x_{1,k_1}),\dots,(x_{m,1},\dots,x_{m,k_m}))\mapsto (x_{1,1},\dots,x_{1,k_1},x_{2,1},\dots,x_{m,1},\dots,x_{m,k_m}),$$
then $T$-algebras (as defined in VI.2 of Maclane *Categories for the Working Mathematician*) is equivalent to the category of monoids, hence $T=U\circ F$, where $U\colon \mathrm{Mon}\to\mathrm{Set}$ is the forgetful functor, and $F\colon\mathrm{Set}\to\mathrm{Mon}$ is the free monoid functor (See, e.g., [Defining multiplication transformation for free monoid monad on monoidal category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607174/defining-multiplication-transformation-for-free-monoid-monad-on-monoidal-categor))

I am interested in replacing $T$ by $T^* \colon\mathrm{Sets}\to\mathrm{Sets}$, the monad which takes $S$ to the set of lists of possibly countably infinite elements of $S$, i.e., $\bigsqcup_{n\ge0}S^n\sqcup S^{\mathbb N}$, again with monad structure $\mu\colon T^* \circ T^* \implies T^*$ given by concatenation (from left to right).

> What is the category of $T^*$-algebras?

If $M\in T^* \mathrm{-alg}$ then it comes with a map $T^* M:=\bigsqcup_{n\ge0}M^n\sqcup M^{\mathbb N}\to M$. Concretely, the restriction to $TM\subset T^* M$ gives $M$ the structure of a monoid. But $M$ also comes with a strange infinite-ary operation $\mu_{\mathbb N}\colon M^{\mathbb N}\to M$. The image of $\mu_{\mathbb N}$ lands in the sub-set $ \{x\in M:\forall y\in M,xy=x\} \subset M$, since concatenation from the right with infinite lists does nothing. However, I am interested in a more concrete description of the category $T^* \mathrm{-alg}$.

Comment: How do you propose to concatenate two infinite lists, i.e.what explicitly is the monad multiplication you have in mind?

Comment: I propose to just take the first infinite list.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan why doesn't the naive choice of a unit $S\hookrightarrow \bigsqcup_{n\ge0}S^n\sqcup S^{\mathbb N}$ work?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's fine. I suppose more generally the proposed concatenation of a possibly infinite list of possibly infinite lists is to concatenate from left to right until the list becomes infinite, then stop?

Comment: Also, several times in this post you say "monad" when you mean "monoid" which I imagine could be confusing to some readers.

Comment: Yes, I suggest to edit this mistake.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I have fixed the typos, thank you for pointing it out. And yes, I mean concatenation from left to right. Particularly interesting is concatenation of infinitely many finite lists.

Comment: I think it should just be "what you think it is," i.e. the category of monoids with an "infinite product" operations that are compatible with the finite one and associative in the appropriate sense.

Comment: @N.Virgo yes, I agree, but I'm wondering if that category is equivalent to a more familiar one: monoids with infinite products is quite difficult to describe.

Comment: One thing I can think of: the infinitary operation must have image which consists of "right-absorbers", i.e. elements $x$ of the monoid such that $xy = x$ for all $y$.  I think maybe, if you have a monoid $M$ with a map $M^\omega \to M$ with image consisting of right-absorbers, and with compatibility with left multiplication in $M$ versus prepending to the infinite list, then that should be enough to describe the $T^*$-algebra.

Comment: Hmm, we might actually not have a monad here.  From your description, I would expect $\mu_X : [ [], [], [], \ldots ] \mapsto []$ which is the identity of the monoid $T^* X$.  On the other hand, since $(T^* X, \mu_X)$ must be a $T^*$-algebra, you would expect the image of $[ [], [], [], \ldots ]$ to be a right-absorber, giving a contradiction.  So in other words, associativity doesn't work on $[ [ [], [], [], \ldots ], [ [x] ] ]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functor $T^*$, with the given $\eta$ and $\mu$, do not form a monad.  To see this, consider a nonempty set $X$ with $x \in X$, and look at the condition for associativity on the element
$[[[], [], [], \ldots], [[x]]] \in (T^*)^3 X$.  On the one hand, $\mu_{T^* X}$ maps this to $[[], [], [], \ldots]$, and applying $\mu_X$ gives $[]$.  On the other hand, $T^* \mu_X$ maps the element to $[[], [x]]$, and applying $\mu_X$ gives $[x]$.  Therefore, the associativity condition fails.

In fact, it is easy to see there is no monad on the functor $T^*$ which extends the list monad.  To see this, we have $[[], [], [], \ldots] \in (T^*)^2 \emptyset$, and the only possible image for $\mu_\emptyset$ of this element in $T^* \emptyset$ is $[]$.  Then, by the naturality of $\mu$, we must have $\mu_X : [[], [], [], \ldots] \mapsto []$ for all sets $X$.  As in the previous paragraph, this gives a contradiction.

---

So at this point, some computer scientist out there might wonder: OK, but the syntactic monad described (which is not semantically a monad) is exactly what the Haskell version of lists amounts to, and we have concrete definitions of the list monad in Haskell.  The resolution: the join operation on $[[], [], [], \ldots]$ will actually enter an infinite loop when trying to head-reduce the result.  So, the join operation of the Haskell list monad is not actually a total function.

It might be possible to model this mathematically by extending the functor to include a possibility of a "partial finite list followed by an infinite loop condition".  Then, for example, you could map the infinite list of empty lists to an empty list followed by an infinite loop condition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Indeed, the motivation for the question came from what the list monad in Haskell is mathematically.

Comment: Another option to resolve this is to consider it a monad not on the category of sets but on some category of partial functions (for example Hask, if you're willing to overlook the question of whether Hask is a category). Then the join operation on $[[],[],[],\dots]$ can just fail to terminate, as it should. This is different from your suggestion because this way an algebra will be a set $M$ equipped with a *partial* function $T^*(M)\to M$ (plus equations). I think this partiality might be connected to the idea that a series might not converge. (@KentaS you might be interested in this comment.)